how to add negative padding to a row in a column
Hi I have a column which has a padding 16.dp, within this column I have various rows but one of the row I do not want to set any padding, but as the column has it and will apply to this row as well.
I want to set negative padding to this row I looked online and tried to use .offset(x = -16.dp) to the row but did not work.
could you please suggest what can be done please
here is my sample code
          Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors =
                        listOf(
                            md_theme_night_dream_start,
                            md_theme_night_dream_end
                        )
                    )
                )
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(
                    vertical = 16.dp,
                    horizontal = 16.dp,
                )
        )
        {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                Color.DarkGray,
                                Color.Black
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .offset(x = -16.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ){

            }
        }

thanks in advance
R
EDIT
hello @BenjyTec apologies for the delay, I am sending you a better example code I tried, above question, main column has padding 16.dp, row above the column fill the whole width and the row inside the column with offset -16.dp does not work. I have also attached a picture
        Column {
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = homeScreenState.notify is AutoRefreshing || homeScreenState.notify is ManualRefreshing) {
            LinearProgressIndicator(
                modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            )
        }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(
                            Color.White,
                            Color.Black
                        )
                    )
                )
                .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {

        }
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors =
                        listOf(
                            md_theme_night_dream_start,
                            md_theme_night_dream_end
                        )
                    )
                )
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(
//                    vertical = 16.dp,
//                    horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_horizontal_small),
                    top = 16.dp,
                    start = 16.dp,
                    bottom = 16.dp,
                    end = 16.dp
                )
        )
        {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                Color.White,
                                Color.Black
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .offset(x = -16.dp)
            ) {

            }}}



The offset Modifier should do the trick. What exactly do you mean by "it did not work"? Can you provide a screenshot?

hello @BenjyTec apologies for the delay, I am sending you a better example code I tried, above question, main column has padding 16.dp, row above the column fill the whole width and the row inside the column with offset -16.dp does not work.
I have also attached a picture
